# User with full control unable to see this options (New,actions,Settings) which are present in peoples and groups SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

[image: *enter image description here*]

Person with full control unable to see options like New, Actions, Settings which are present inside this people and groups. and idea whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Are you looking at “All People”? Change to a particular SharePoint group, such as “Site Members” group.

Comment: We are looking in all SharePoint group

Answer (score 0):

There is no "New" operation in "All People" (User Information List). And only site admins can use "Settings"（List Settings) in "All People" (User Information List). For these operations, you need to open a particular group.